# Reloading page partially in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm developing a music website in Rails. The landing page is divided and has a search form where you can look up bands stored in the DB. Inside the other division I embedded a player reproducing some random videos. I want the search results being displayed on the same landing page.

When I submit the form the page reloads and the player reloads also and starts playing a different video. What I actually want to achieve is that the player doesn't get interrupted while the search form is submitted.

Don't know if and how this is possible the way I want it. If I got it right [this link](http://mrdanadams.com/2011/partials-ajax-form-submit-rails/) describes one way to do that but I didn't get it to work.

home controller

```
def index
  @bands = Band.search(params[:search]).order("name ASC")
  @random_band = Band.order("RANDOM()").limit(1) 
end

def preview
  @bands = Band.search(params[:search]).order("name ASC")
  render :partial => 'preview', :content_type => 'text/html'
end
```

_preview.html.erb

```
<table class="table"  
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Year</th>
  </tr>
  <% @bands.each do |f| %>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <%= f.name %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

home#index

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">

    <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
      <%= form_tag({:action => 'preview'}, id: "search-form", :remote => true, :'data-update-target' => 'update-container') do %>
      <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Bands" %>
      <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
      <% end %>
     </form>



<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">

    <div id="update-container">
      <%= @random_band.first.name %>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <%= video_tag("#{@random_band.first.name}.mp4", size: "460x390",
        controls: true, autobuffer: true, autoplay: true) %>
   </div>
 </div>


</html>
```

application.js

```
$(function() {
/* Convenience for forms or links that return HTML from a remote ajax call.
The returned markup will be inserted into the element id specified.
 */
$('form[data-update-target]').live('ajax:success', function(evt, data) {
    var target = $(this).data('update-target');
    $('#' + target).html(data);
  });
});
```

First problem: The form doesn't seem to find the preview action.

Second problem: If I change the content of the index with the preview action it does find the preview action obviously but it doesn't render the search results inside the update-container. Instead it renders them as a whole new page.

By the way, I know my way around Rails a bit but I've got absolutely no experience with Ajax.

Comment: First, where are you setting the `@random_band`? And is there a reason why you created an extra controller method for this really simple search function?

Comment: I edited the home controller in order to give the information you requested.

Comment: The reason the preview action exists is simply that I tried to stick to the mentioned tutorial where they use it that way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got most of your code very twisted and not really lean as far as I can tell. The short and very lean way to get your search results updated without reloading the rest of the page (including your player) could look like this. The index function should look like this:

```
//bands_controller.rb
def index
  @bands = Band.search(params[:search])
end
```

You have to create the search-method inside of your Band-Model:

```
//Band.rb
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['name LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

You need to render your _preview.html.erb inside a div with a certain ID somewhere inside your view:

```
<div id="bands"><%= render 'preview' %></div>
```

Your form_tag has a lot of arguments that you won't need anymore:

```
<%= form_tag bands_path, :method => 'get', :id => "search_form" do %>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

The jquery I use for my forms looks like this.. Pretty simple in my opinion:

```
$(function() {
  $("#search_form input").keyup(function() {
    $.get($("#search_form").attr("action"), $("#search_form").serialize(), null, "script");
    return false;
  });
});
```

This fires the index.js.erb (you will have to create that) everytime you put a letter into your search field:

```
//index.js.erb (same folder as index.html.erb)
$("#bands").html("<%= escape_javascript(render("preview")) %>");
```

This should refresh your div. It's maybe a little work but that's the easiest way to implement an ajax search function into your index page that I could think of.

Sources:
[Railscast#27](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form)
[Railscast#240](http://railscasts.com/episodes/240-search-sort-paginate-with-ajax)

Comment: Had to make some changes but the general approach worked very well. find(:all) doesn't work in Rails 4 anymore and the partial _preview shouldn't be prefixed by the underscore. Also in index.js.erb: render("bands") should really be render("preview") in this case.

Comment: Yes, thanks has been really late last night. Changed your fixes in my answer. Thanks for accepting. Good luck with your project.